# Cron in heroku but update files

Tags: flask, heroku, cron

I'm currently developing a screener webapp using heroku. The data is saved in csv (because its is a screener, it takes a lot of time to run if using api). Right now, I updated manually by updating and saving the data in my local then push it to heroku.
Is there a way to cron so that it updates the csv data once a day?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dynos have an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make will be lost when the dynos restart. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

For this reason, file-based data stores are not recommended on Heroku. If you move your data into a client-server database (Heroku's own [Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) would be a good fit or you can pick [something else](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores)), you could easily updated it whenever you like.

The [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) can be used to run tasks daily. Write a script to update your database table and schedule it to run whenever you like.